# Group by different subsets of keys

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a table of products sales

```
id  product_id  price_sold
1      1            500
2      1            300
3      2            100
4      3            200
5      3            100
```

I want to be able to sum the prices by different subsets of products, say: sum of prices per the group of proucts 1,2. and another calculation of sum of prices per the group of products 2,3, so the needed result will be:

```
group 1, 900
group 2, 400
```

Can you help with efficient and elegant way to do that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Doing what you want is a bit challenging, because the groups overlap.  You have two options. The first is to do conditional aggregation and put the results in columns:

```
select sum(case when product_id in (1, 2) then price_sold end) as group1,
       sum(case when product_id in (2, 3) then price_sold end) as group2
from productsales ps;
```

To get the results on separate rows, you could then pivot this result.  Or, you could do the calculation directly. For this to work, you need to construct a table describing the groups:

```
select pg.grpid, sum(ps.price_sold)
from productsales ps
join
(
  select 1 as grpid, 1 as product_id
  union all
  select 1 as grpid, 2 as product_id
  union all
  select 2 as grpid, 2 as product_id
  union all
  select 2 as grpid, 3 as product_id
) pg on ps.product_id = pg.product_id
group by pg.grpid;
```

Answer (score 0):

[**SQL Fiddle**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/07bc2d/6/0):

```
SELECT 'GROUP 1' AS `Group`, SUM(price_sold) AS PriceSum
FROM MyTable
WHERE product_id = 1 OR product_id = 2
UNION
SELECT 'GROUP 2', SUM(price_sold)
FROM MyTable
WHERE product_id = 2 OR product_id = 3
```

The result looks like:

[image]

Comment: Make this `UNION ALL`, as you don't want the dbms to do the work to look out for duplicates where there can be none.